# Retail POS for non-profit

Tags: gratis, open-source, inventory, point-of-sale

We are a team of teens who are selling fair-trade products in our high school. Our biggest problem is the consumption of paper. We would then turn to a completely computerized and paperless solution.

Currently, we need these features:

- Inventory
- Sales
- Employee / attendance
- Free software, or no monthly cost
- Preferable running on a Windows or Linux or Android. All these choice are avaible. Mac and iOS are too expensive.

Also: keep in mind that we are a non-profit organisation and in an education context.

Comment: For Android, I know of two candidates listed with my [Barcode inventory apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory#group_34): there're [StarCode Express](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.isasconsulting.starcode.lite) and [ACE Mobile POS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ACEretail.mobile) you might wish to take a look at. The latter sounds like bound to a specific product, though, but the former might fit. Even offers a PC counterpart. I've not tried any of them, hence just a comment :)

Comment: PS: Also check [TabShop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.smartlab.tshop), which might even fit better. From the app description, it is completely independent from any "cloud service", though the Pro version can make use of some (Google Docs for exchanging stuff).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the answer. I will review it with my team and decide wich one we should use.

Comment: Anytime. I'm just looking at the list initially mentioned to see if I find more candidates. Just created a new section [POS with barcode support](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory#group_1074) you might wish to bookmark for review. When you found a good candidate, please feel encouraged to [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with some details included, as all I can give here are hints/comments :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I can also recommend [Tabshop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.smartlab.tshop) mentioned in comments above.
I use it for a mobile shop for a couple of months now. See the link for full description. it offers sales, inventory, barcode scanning, etc. It is also very easy to use and setup.

The only thing it does not have is your "employee/attendance" requirement.

In future, if you want to sync with the cloud, you can purchase the Pro version (a few bucks). It has an API so can be used to sync both products/sales with an ecommerce solution of choice. I am using this too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we will take a look at it. However, we would like to have employees management in the app.

Comment: If that's important for you, then look at a Windows or Linux based open source product called [unicentaopos](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unicentaopos/) which enables creation of users.

Comment: We already tried this, and we should go with this if there is nothing more nice.

Comment: No problem. The other alternative if you use Tabshop it to use Android's user management if it still exists in recent versions.

Comment: Tabshop also now has user managment, but no timekeeping. What did you go with in the end?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenBravo](http://www.openbravo.com/) has these features. It is free open source.

Inventory:

[image: OpenBravo inventory]

Sales:

[image: OpenBravo sales]

Employees:

[image: OpenBravo employees]

Payroll:

[image: OpenBravo payroll]

You can run the OpenBravo server on any server, in your case it can be your laptop. OpenBravo's web interface can be accessed from a web browser on the laptop itself or any other on the same network (username/password required).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It was our choice number two, however it was too complicated for the end user.